# ajax display text on submit

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a simple form with a submit button (below).  I am trying to let the user type in the text box then when he/she clicks submit the page will refresh and echo out what they typed in a div.  The data the user types is stored in a database before being echoed.  The problem is that when I click submit, the input doesnt show immediatly.  I have to click refresh for it to show and when I do my browser gives me a popup (safari) asking to resend the data.  This will result in duplicate data inserted in the DB.  I have a feeling I need to use javascript and I could also make it more elegant with a fadeIn, but I dont know how to do that. I guess I'm asking if there's a way to use javascript to take a user's text and insert it into a mysql DB and also display it after submit is clicked all on 1 or 0 (prefereably) refreshes. thanks

Here's my code:

```
<form method='POST'  action='index.php'>
<input type='text' name='text' id='text'>
<input type ='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<?php
$input=$_POST['text'];
$put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$input')");

echo "<div id='area'>";
//i connect to the DB and echo out the data here

echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: is that the complete and exact code that you are running, because I find nothing weird in it, assuming that 'index.php' is the script. A reason however for why you have to refresh for your data to show might be that the first time the data did not insert. Did you try doing an `echo $input;`, in the second line after where $input is assigned, in your PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the php statements before you're actual html code and would modify you're code like this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['text']))
{
  $input = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);

  $put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$input')"); //At this point the info has been put inside the DB

  echo "<div id='area'>";
  //i connect to the DB and echo out the data here
  echo mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
  echo "</div>";
}
?>

<form method='POST'  action='index.php'>
<input type='text' name='text' id='text'>
<input type ='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

The reason why you don't see it is that the HTML is loaded before you php I think.  So I would do a php page where all the sql treatement would be done and once that is done recal you index.php and in there query you're information from the database.

Comment: @dtbarne Are you shure not taking the info from the database is a safe way.  What makes you shure that the data was properly pushed into the database? (Question for my personnale information :) )

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside SQL injection attacks your code is vulnerable with, the standard practice is to respond to the POST with a redirect back to where the form was. In your case, it will be the page which runs `SELECT from table`.

Comment: @kotepillar index.php is that page

Answer (score 0):

No need to use AJAX here. Just make sure that you do one of the following:

1. Make sure you SELECT from the DB *after* you have INSERTed the data.
2. Better, is that `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`, then rather than performing an extra SQL query, just display the POSTed value since you already know it.

A side note on your code sample. If you don't have `magic_quotes` enabled, it's susceptible to SQL injection, so make sure you properly escape user input before using it in queries.